# best way to count pulses in 1-D waveform in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, vectorization

I have a signal composed of square pulses (+ some noise), here's a tiny part of it:

[image]

I look for an efficient and robust way to count how many pulses I have.

Here's what I've done so far:

The amplitude is a bit noisy but SNR is great do I can threshold:

```
data = data>1;
```

the length of each pulse can be noisy so I ignore it and use `diff`, to obtain the derivatives (+ and -), find how many non-zero elements there are, and divide by 2 (since there are 2 derivative peaks per pulse) .

```
dd=diff(data);

num_of_pulses=length(find(diff(dd)))/2
```

Is that the best way to do that? I was told not to use `diff` because it can be too noisy...

Comment: [This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) function can help.

Comment: But it is slower (by factor >20), and also find false peaks unless I threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description of the data, I think this will work.

```
numberOfPulses = nnz(diff(data > 1) > 0)
```

You can reliably find pulse samples using `data > 1`, then use `diff() > 0` find the transitions from no pulse to pulse, and finally `nnz()` to count them.

Comment: thanks! while this is on par in performance  with what I suggested, you gave ne the idea to use `sum` instead of `nnz`, and I got it even faster!